# Is there a way to hide a div in mobile view on a non-responsive site?

Tags: html, mobile, hide

I'm looking for a way to hide a div when the user is using a mobile device, but does not have a responsive website. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

inyour css file

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
    #divid{
       display: none;
    }
}
```

you still have to see what is the max resolution where you want the div hidden

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish that with a bit of javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 640) {
        $("#div").css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS or Javascript and what devices?

Using CSS you can

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mobile.css" media="handheld">
```

use a mobile.css on your site and hide a div in that CSS. But people downloading browsers to their devices starts to make determining if you are on a mobile device more complicated. I think firefox has a problem with that specific code.

A referance to media handheld is here http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html

More media refs are available here http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/mediaqueries

An opensource mobile detection site is here http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/